# Kinect SDK for finger detection?

Tags: c#, sdk, tracking, kinect

I'm a student from Nanyang Technological University (NTU), Singapore. And currently developing a project using Kinect SDK.

And my question is, anyone know how to develop a program to detect a finger (or fingertip) using Kinect SDK, or maybe even some possible reference codes. Anyway, I also tried to search on google, but the only reference I got is using Open NI, instead of Kinect SDK.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: The official SDK does not have the capacity for this.

Answer (score 10):

I was looking into that myself, although haven't gone deep into it.

OpenNI has some constants for finger tip/wrist detection, but that's not implemented yet,
but that's not an option for your setup anyway.

Here's a list of resources that hopefully will get you started:

- [MIT CSAIL Hand detection](http://www.csail.mit.edu/node/1392)

[image: MIT CSAIL hand detection]

- FORTH ICS - [Efficient model-based 3D tracking of hand articulations using Kinect](http://www.ics.forth.gr/~argyros/research/kinecthandtracking.htm)

[image: Forth ICS hand tracking]

- [Candescent NUI project](http://candescentnui.codeplex.com/)

[image: Candescent NUI hand sample1]

[image: Candescent NUI hand sample1]

- [Other random videos](http://wn.com/Kinect_Hand_Detection)

Comment: I tried FORTH's demo project and found the hand tracking to be inconsistent. There is another project called Finger Precise Tracking made by 3Gear: http://www.openni.org/files/finger-precise-tracking/. I've tested both the original demo which compares hands to a set of poses and the beta version for their true hand tracker which seems to work better than FORTH's. It's worth a look if you haven't seen it already.