# How to install both Windows and Open Source Kinect drivers

Tags: driver, kinect, device-driver, kinect-sdk, openkinect

I'm able to get both the open source kinect drivers and the Windows drivers working correctly for my xbox kinect, but I am not able to keep both on the same machine when using one or the other. What is the reason for that? And what can I do so that I don't have to totally uninstall all Kinect related things when I am testing out a gesture library that might be open source or require the Windows Kinect SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can only have 1 driver per device, so I'm afraid you can't use both OpenKinect/libfreenct and the Kinect for Windows(MS Kinect SDK) at once.

However you can either use OpenNI 1.5.x with this [Kinect-OpenNI bridge](https://code.google.com/p/kinect-mssdk-openni-bridge/),
or [OpenNI 2](http://openni.org) [with Kinect for Windows](http://www.openni.org/files/ni-mate/)

I assume it might be simpler to use a single kinect library. 
Nite(which ships with OpenNI) provides some gestures.
I'm not sure if the latest Kinect for Windows does too.

You can still use skeleton tracking to implement your own gestures.
You can use a number of algorithms, for example Dynamic Time Warping
(here's a [Kinect for Windows](http://kinectdtw.codeplex.com/) library)
I also recommend having a look at [Gesture Recognition Toolkit(GRT)](http://www.nickgillian.com/software/grt)
as it provides a number of various algorithms nicely explained [wiki](http://www.nickgillian.com/wiki/pmwiki.php/GRT/GestureRecognitionToolkit)
and since it's generic you can use with either openni or kinect for windows
(not to mention wiimotes/IMUs/etc.)

Comment: I tried installing that Kinect-OpenNI bridge, and the installer kept crashing for me. Also, my application will only be focusing on the hands of the user, and their body won't be in view at all, so a lot of the libraries that do hand gesture recognition also require a skeleton to be tracked and I couldn't use those ones. I'll look into what you mentioned though. But you answered the original question satisfactorily, so I'll accept this.

Comment: Feel free to vote/tick as you see fit ;). Also, if it's hands you're interested another option is using the kinect's depth image to isolate the hands, then use opencv for finger detection which can then be mapped to gestures. Here are a few more resources that could be useful: [Kinect Hand Tracking](http://kinecthandtracking.codeplex.com/) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047039/kinect-sdk-for-finger-detection/9057781#9057781) (I think [Forth ICS's method is now integrated with OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/files/3d-hand-tracking-library/))