# Finger Position Detection using Kinect

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect, kinect.toolbox, kinect-interaction

Are there any open libraries or opensource codes available for finger position detection using Kinect ?
I have tried searching OpenNI and other libraries for Kinect but could'nt find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking into this a few years ago, you can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047039/kinect-sdk-for-finger-detection/9057781#9057781) from then which includes a few options.

Links may be a bit outdates, for example Apple bought OpenNI, so the Forth ICS project can now be found [here](http://cvrlcode.ics.forth.gr/handtracking/)

You didn't mention which version of the kinect, so I'll assume it's the original kinect for xbox 360.

If you're not constrained to using kinect only, you might actually want to try the [Intel RealSense SDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/realsense/devkit) as it already includes [hand tracking](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/Hand_Tracking.pdf)(pdf tutorial link) and the c++ sdk has wrappers for c#/java and makes the data available through websockets.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeHey I am using kinect 360 .Could you tell me a single link which gives the overall process regarding installation of libraries ,setup etc

Comment: For the Forth ICS version, simply follow [their instructions](http://cvrlcode.ics.forth.gr/handtracking/#a_download) for what to download/install prior to running their demos. Note that these are 64bit Windows